# css background gradient with background image in css3 on two different classes

Tags: css, input

Is it possible to define a background image and a background gradient on two different classes for the same element?

```
input[type=password] {
    background-image: url(/images/icons/glyphicons_203_lock.png);
    background-size: 17px auto;
    background-position: 9px 5px;
}


.err input[name] {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffdddd 0%, #ffeeee 100%);
}
```

What happens is the icon is missing when there is an error.

I'm using "less" if that helps at all, what I want to avoid is having to define each icon on each .err element individually, this would be a lot of repeat code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are using, gradient will override the image, because gradient is also an image so you can use CSS3 multiple backgrounds by separating the image and a gradient like this, it will give you image and a gradient

```
background-image: url('url'), -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffdddd, #ffeeee);
```

Comment: so it's not possible to do it on seperate classes? There's no background-gradient property or anything?

Comment: what you exactly want is an icon with a gradient right so you need to define in one else the other will take over else you can try this 1, learn specificity

Comment: what i want is to define an .error class, and not have to define all the different icons in the error class for each field.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way i can use .less to not have to put the image on each .err[name=foo] class.

Comment: ok, i tried doing this but I have a problem now, because the gradient is also a background-image, I cannot use background-position and background-size for just the icon.

Comment: @chovy **LESS** is nothing but it just makes your work easy, in the end it is oing to compile in a normal CSS code so don't expect that you can achieve alien things using LESS :)

Comment: I saved some code duplication using mixins and passing in the background image to a less mixin.